# Functions as values of an object's property and their respective names

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have the following code:

```
function createPerson(name) {
  return {
    talk: () => `I am ${name}`,
    age:23
  }
}
```

1. If I do `obj=createPerson`, `obj` receives the object `{ talk: [Function: talk], age: 23 }`, right?
2. What I don't understand is why the function `() => I am ${name}` is refered by `obj.talk()`. Is this common syntaxe that I should know?

In the following code, I assign an object to `obj`:

```
function createPerson(name) {
  return {
    talk: function speak (surname) {
      return name+" "+surname
    } ,
    age:23
  }
}
let obj=createPerson("John")
```

3. Now, `obj.talk()` is a function that receives the parameter `surname`. My question here is: why doesn't the name of the function *(speak)* matter to the code?

Comment: Because it's a function reference; it's only marginally important how the function was defined, arrow function vs function expression.

Comment: The fact that it is named doesn't affect your example and it could just as well be anonymous (though if you `console.log(obj.talk.name);` it will log `speak`), but in general naming functions is the main mechanism allowing for them to be referenced more than once (assigning them to a variable or in this case property is another). see: [Function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Comment: Using a function as a property is how you define object methods.

Comment: The function name would be useful in the code if it were recursive. Otherwise, it's just useful for debugging.

Comment: As Dave said, the function name is just a convenience to refer to the function. A single function can have many different variables and properties referencing it, the function itself doesn't know or care what references it. Only garbage collection cares, so that when there are no references it can clear out the space used by the function at a time it sees fit. Oh, debuggers etc. care too but again that's for human convenience, it's not fundamental to how the code works.